# AWS Lambda Function URL is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am learning a AWS Lambda. As a youtube vedio, After I create a Java lambda function, as mentioned in the vedio, I go to AWS lambda -> function -> configuration tab and try to find "Function URL" but there is no more such option before.

[image]

Would anyone know why?

Expect there is a "Function URL" between "Destination" and "Enviornment Variables"

Comment: What AWS region are you using?

Comment: [Lambda function URLs - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) mentions: "Function URLs are **not supported** in the following regions: Asia Pacific (Hyderabad) (ap-south-2), Asia Pacific (Melbourne) (ap-southeast-4), Europe (Spain) (eu-south-2), Europe (Zurich) (eu-central-2), Israel (Tel Aviv) (il-central-1), and Middle East (UAE) (me-central-1)."

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein , would you please leave a standard comment here? I then I could approve you and close the questrion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Lambda function URLs - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) (as at February 2024):

> **Function URLs are not supported** in the following regions:
>
> - Asia Pacific (Hyderabad) (ap-south-2)
> - Asia Pacific (Melbourne) (ap-southeast-4)
> - Europe (Spain) (eu-south-2)
> - Europe (Zurich) (eu-central-2)
> - Israel (Tel Aviv) (il-central-1)
> - Middle East (UAE) (me-central-1)

So, it seems that you might be in one of those regions.